# adding extra rows according to column values(SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Year    Life    Method
1         9       x
2         9       x
4         9       x
2         10      y
4         10      y
```

**Table A**
I have table something like above.

I wanna get as below.

```
Year    Life    Method
1        9        x
2        9        x
3        9        x
4        9        x
5        9        x
1       10        y
2       10        y
3       10        y
4       10        y
5       10        y
```

**Table B**
Mean to say every life and method have year of 1 to 5.

How can i create a tableB using Table B. using SQL query.

any idea?

Comment: If every life an method have year 1 to 5, why do you need the column year in table a? I would create a temp table with five rows 1 to 5 an CROSS JOIN it with table A's columns Life and Method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 select b.yr, a.life, a.method 
 from (select distinct life,method from tableA) a,
 (select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5) b
```

This will do a cross join and get you the desired result.

Edit: Creating a temp table to deal with many year values

```
DROP TABLE Numbers;
CREATE TABLE Numbers (Num INT NOT NULL);
DECLARE @x INT;
SELECT @x = 1;
WHILE @x <= 60 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Numbers(Num) VALUES (@x);
SELECT @x = @x + 1;
END;
```

The query would then be

```
select n.yr, a.life, a.method 
from (select distinct life,method from tableA) a,
Numbers n
```

Or you can use `union` statements shown above if you have to do this ad-hoc.

```
select 1 union select 2 union ...union select n
```

Comment: Thanks, This seems to work for me if i have 5 rows. actual the year column goes till 60. You have any solution for that?

Comment: check the modified version.

Comment: It Worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `method` has the same value for `life`, then you can do something like this:

```
with nums as (
      select row_number() over (order by (select null)) as n
      from master..spt_values
     )
select n.n as year, l.life, l.method
from nums n cross join
          (select life, method from table t) l 
where n.n <= 5;
```

Comment: may be `(select distinct life, method from table t)` ?